# Calculating 2^N in C# with long data type where N is 1929439432949324

Tags: c#, numbers, exponential

Currently I need to calculate `2^N`, however `N` can be as large as 1929238932899 and I'm stuck using a long data type which can't hold a number that large.

I've currently tried converting to 'BigInt' however I'm still stuck with the long data type restriction from what I've seen as well.

I have a function which calculates the power. However, with the long data type, it just returns 0 when the number gets too big. Note that this is just a generic recursive power function.

For example, with `2^6` its meant to return 64 and with `2^47` to return 140737488355328. However, when it becomes `2^8489289`, it just returns 0.

Comment: Obviously `long` can only fir 2^63... So far it is very unclear what you are trying to achieve with long values...

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your attempt so far.

Comment: Thats the issue that I'm having is that a long data type can only hold 2^63 however I need to calculate far greater than that, I'm thinking I can calculate it using Recursion / Simulation or Binary Representation of decimals but having a lot of issues with those methods, as well as code isn't my issue here so a minimal reproducible is kinda pointless as I need a workaround the long data type

Comment: `2^8489289` is fairly extreme already and `2^1929238932899` is a whole other level. What do you use this for? There is often a way to avoid working *directly* with such huge numbers with some mathematical shortcuts.

Comment: Hi Harold, my issue isn't with calculating it per say, its with representing that number in a long data type somehow.

Comment: If you don't need to represent that as decimal, that's pretty easy - 2^N can be written in binary as 1 followed by N zeroes...

Comment: @Murls representing the number implicitly is not a problem: `2^1929238932899` is a representation. But whether that is a useful representation depends on how you want to manipulate that number.

Comment: What do you mean by " I need to calculate 2^N"? You cannot view this number on a screen, because you won't have enough time in your life.

Comment: A lot of clever people have come up with a cunning way to represent large numbers in the same number of bytes as a long. It's called `double`. But even that isn't going to be able to represent `2^1929238932899 `...

Comment: A [quick calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177978/126951) shows that if you were to try to print out the value of `2^1929238932899` and you were able to print one BILLION digits per second, it will still take nearly 10 minutes to print it out... With a more realistic million digits per second, it would take nearly a week. What are you actually intending to do with the results of such a calculation?

Comment: I've solved the issue, I managed to find a workaround by converting it to binary and then calculating it in binary and then using the binary representation to do my calculations and then output it back as a long data type. For those saying it would take 10 minutes to print out, I got my entire function to work in 0.00001 seconds.

Comment: It would take a lot longer than 10 minutes to print out the value (in decimal), but you're not printing it out so there's no comparison to be made. The big problem with your question is that you didn't state what you were actually going to do with the value, so nobody could really help you effectively.

Answer (score 2):

To represent 2^N in binary form, you need N+1 bits (binary digits), that is

(1 929 439 432 949 324 + 1) / 8 = 241 179 929 118 665.6 bytes ~ 219 PiB for a single number, if you really want to work with it.

Or you can just write down 2^N in binary form: 1 followed by N zeroes.

Comment: Don't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_

Answer (score 1):

Since 2^N is an integer, you can represented it using [Integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

You can put that in a class like this:

```
class FactorizedInteger {

    private Dictionary<long, long> _factors = new Dictionary<long, long>();

    public FactorizedInteger(long radix, long exponent) {
        _factors[radix] = exponent;
    }

    public void Add(FactorizedInteger other) {
        foreach(var factor in other._factors) {
            if (_factors.ContainsKey(factor.Key)) {
                _factors[factor.Key] += factor.Value;
            } else {
                _factors[factor.Key] = factor.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return "(" + String.Join(" + ", _factors.Select(p => $"{p.Key}^{p.Value}")) + ")";
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can even add some mathematical operations without exhausting the memory of the computer. I've included Add as an example.

To use it:

```
        var e1 = new FactorizedInteger(2, 1929238932899);
        var e2 = new FactorizedInteger(2, 64);
        Console.WriteLine(e1);

        e1.Add(e2);
        Console.WriteLine(e1);
```

Output:

```
(2^1929238932899)
(2^1929238932963)
```

This example needs to be made much smarter to be really usefull, but it is a possible representation of such large numbers.

Comment: Don't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_